# split file after a match at the end of the file and keep the match inside file unix

Tags: unix, awk, split, csplit

i have a file that contains random lines and key words END:

```
line 1
line 2
...
line 23
END
line 25
....
line 40
END
```

and i want to split it into multiple files based on the key word END and have it inside each file as:
file 1

```
line 1
line 2
...
line 23
END
```

file 2

```
line 25
.....
line 40
END
```

I tried:

```
csplit -k file_name '/END/' '{*}' but i do not get the correct output.
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an offset of 1 to the regex to include the matching `END` in the current file. I also added to `^` and `$` to anchor the regex.

```
csplit -k file -f file --elide-empty-files '/^END$/1' '{*}'
```

- `-f file` Sets the output filename prefix
- `--elide-empty-files` This is a GNU extension and doesn't output empty files (in this case an empty file `file02`)

Output:

```
$ head file0*
==> file00 <==
line 1
line 2
...
line 23
END

==> file01 <==
line 25
....
line 40
END
```

Comment: TIL `--elide-empty-files` switch.

Answer (score 2):

with `awk`

```
$ awk '{f= FILENAME"."(c+1); print > f} /^END$/{close(f); c++}' file

$ head file.*

==> file.1 <==
line 1
line 2
...
line 23
END

==> file.2 <==
line 25
....
line 40
END
```

**Edge case behavior:**
if the input file is empty (no lines), no output will be generated.
if the file has blank line(s), exact copy of the file is generated as a partition (same as with no `END` marker or only one at the end).